# Find a function M

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Let $x(t)$ be a real valued vector. Can you find a function M such that

$\dot{M}=\frac{\text{d}M}{\text{d}t}=\dot{x}^T\dot{x}$.

I have tried

$M=\dot{x}^Tx,
M=x^Tx$

and many more which don't work. I know that if $x(t)$ is continuous then so will

$\dot{M}=\dot{x}^T\dot{x}$

be and thus M will exist. But how do i find this M?

Comment: $\dot{x}$ continuous $\iff$ $x$ is $C^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible a general formula even in dimension 1. In the case, you are asking for
$$\int(x'(t))^2\,dt$$
and no such formula exists. In *concrete* cases *maybe* you can do the integral.

Comment: Wouldn't this integral exist if x'(t) is continuous?

Comment: @hola, it will *exist*. But you are asking for a *formula*.

Comment: @hola, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral/202.